# Structures with variables of each other type

Tags: c

I have two structures `DirFileArray` and `dirFile` that has variables of each other types. My Eclipse IDE is angry about that, because first structure does't see type of second one ('dirFile' could not be resolved). How to make both structures see each other?

```
struct dirFile;
```

I have added line at the top, put this does't help.

```
struct DirFileArray {
  dirFile *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
}

struct dirFile
{
    int  contentType ;
    char name [STR_SHORT];
    struct DirFileArray * content;
};
```

Comment: Is this a C++ question? In C, structures are not automatically typedefed.

Comment: Hmm. In your code `DirFileArray` is a variable not a structure.

Comment: corrected, but this doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "forward declare those arrays". Remember when you learned to use a function that would be later defined, what did you do? You would write:

```
int func_to_be_defined_later(int param); /* for example */

int main(void)
{
    return func_to_be_defined_later(10);
}

int func_to_be_defined_later(int param)
{
    return param + 1;
}
```

It's similar with structs:

```
/* forward declaration */
struct DirFileArray;
struct dirFile;

struct DirFileArray {       /* note: you had misplaced the struct name */
    struct dirFile *array;  /* note: you forgot struct */
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
};

struct dirFile
{
    int  contentType ;
    char name [STR_SHORT];
    struct DirFileArray *dirFile;
};
```

---

It is worth noting that you can only *point* to forward declared structures (including the structure being declared) not have a variable of them. The reason is that the compiler knows how to allocate a pointer and how much space to give it, but it doesn't know how to allocate the struct and what is it's `sizeof` yet.

In fact, having two structs that contain a variable of the other's type, or a struct that contains a variable of its own type (not a pointer), is a bit of a contradiction. Try to think what would the `sizeof` such structs would be.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forward declaration:

```
struct dirFile;

struct {
  dirFile *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} DirFileArray;

struct dirFile
{
    int  contentType ;
    char name [STR_SHORT];
    struct DirFileArray * dirFile;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple forward declaration will do the trick.

You could look at `typedef` for a more complex include issue

```
struct dirFile;

struct {
  dirFile *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} DirFileArray;

struct dirFile
{
    int  contentType ;
    char name [STR_SHORT];
    struct DirFileArray * dirFile;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, use forward declaration.

```
typedef struct DirFileArray_s DirFileArray;
typedef struct dirFile_s dir_File;

struct DirFileArray_s {
    ...
}

struct DirFileArray_s {
    ...
}
```

I would suggest double think this though as such nesting is nasty.